# Sphinx: How to find related content

Tags: sphinx

Is there a way to find related articles of a given article in sphinx? I will be using the title and the articles content for the query. I need something like lucenes `More like this` feature. How can I do this in Sphinx?

Comment: what makes an article related in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use quorum from your 'title' words to get similar documents, ie "greatest cars in england"/2 gives you list of related documents. You could narrow you search by excluding common words, articles by building stopwords list and issue "call keywords" request to daemon.